# can std::async int a function quit out before task is finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, c++17

my code is below:

```
void f1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        std::cout << "f1: " << i << std::endl;
    }
}

void f2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "f2: " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
auto fz = []() {
        auto l_future = std::async(std::launch::async, f1);
        auto r_future = std::async(std::launch::async, f2);
        while (!is_ready(r_future)) {}
        std::cout << "right done" << std::endl;
    };

fz();
std::cout << "one of task done" << std::endl;
```

the result is that "right done" is printed but fz() is not finished."one of task done" is printed until the f1 is finished. Now i want to print "one of task done" before f1 is finished.How can i do?

Comment: The problem is that the `std::future` destructor waits until the result is ready. Note that this is a special behavior of `std::future` objects that were created with `std::async`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future

Answer (score 6):

From [this `std::async` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

> If the `std::future` obtained from `std::async` is not moved from or bound to a reference, the destructor of the `std::future` will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes

When the lambda ends and the two `std::future` objects are destructed, the destruction of `l_future` will block until the function `f1` returns.

Answer (score 6):

Your code hangs in [1] line

```
auto fz = []() {
        auto l_future = std::async(std::launch::async, f1);
        auto r_future = std::async(std::launch::async, f2);
        while (!is_ready(r_future)) {}
        std::cout << "right done" << std::endl;
        // [1]
    };
```

because dtor of future waits for a result.

You can return `future` from your lambda, and after cout call `get` to wait for a result i.e. until `f1` task is completion:

```
auto fz = []() {
        auto l_future = std::async(std::launch::async, f1);
        auto r_future = std::async(std::launch::async, f2);
        while (!is_ready(r_future)) {}
        std::cout << "right done" << std::endl;
        return l_future; // move future outside lambda
    };

auto fut = fz();
std::cout << "one of task done" << std::endl;
fut.get();
```